# MobileVLCKit authentication

Tags: authentication, rtsp, libvlc

I am looking at MobileVLCKit for at video project where I do RTSP streams on IOS.

I have run into a problem though, that I hope some can help me with, as I I have not been able to find anything useable through hours of Googling :)

The stream requires user authentication (basic auth), and when I provide the stream with the username and password included in the URL, everything works fine. However, when I do not include it the stream obviously does not work. What I had expected was either to get some sort of indication that was a `401` error happening or that I was requested to provide username and password by the framework.

Hope someone can shed some light on this problem :)

Comment: It turns out that it seems to be something about IOS 10 and deprecated dialogues in the VLC code. I tried running the code on an IOS 9 device, with no difference though. I ended up implementing the check for authentication manually with sockets.